# Setting z-index of multiple background colors in DataGridView rows/cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have enabled full row selection in my DataGridView so that when a row is clicked on, the entire row is highlighted blue. To achieve this I used the following code:

`this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

However, I also occasionally change the background color of a row or cell based on certain events. To do this, I'm just accessing the row's `DefaultCellStyle` and setting the `BackColor` to green. However, whenever I change the color and the row is already selected, the blue selected highlight has priority and it is not apparent that the row has any cells that are green. I'd like the green cells to display on top of the blue highlighted row.

Is there anyway to set the priority/z-index of my rows/cells so that the `SelectionMode` property is always placed in the background and my other colors are always layered on top?

Comment: For the rows which you change their `BackColor`, set `SelectionBackColor` to the same color which you used as `BackColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rows or cells  which you change their `BackColor`, set `SelectionBackColor` to the same color which you used as `BackColor`.

For example for a specific row:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

Or for a specific cell:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was very clear in my question. I'm occasionally changing the cell color to green, but the row selection mode is set to blue and superseding it (it is displaying as a full blue row). I'd like for the green cell background to be on top of the blue row background when that row is selected. Will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: No problem, do the same thing with `Cell` instead of `Row`.

Comment: For row change `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor`, for cell `Style.SelectionBackColor`.